# Css3 one of the div corners should inwards

Tags: html, css

I have created one div with following css properties.

```
<div class="mainDiv border-5"></div>
.mainDiv { border:1px solid black; height:auto; padding: 5px;} 
.border-5 { -webkit-border-radius: 15px; -moz-border-radius: 15px; border-radius: 15px;  }
```

The above code creates a div with all corners normally.I want one of the corner to be inwards i.e., the corner should come from inside.